# How to input equations in MATLAB and operate on them?

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB R2013a. I want to input an equation in Matlab, e.g., $f(x) = x^2 - 2 x + 3$. I want it to be inputted by the user. I use the `inline` function for this:

```
func = input('Enter a function: ','s');
f = inline(func);
```

I have been able to do some work with this, but I want to differentiate the equation. I was trying to use the `diff` function for this, but it doesn't work. Using `diff(f,x);` results in an error. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: It might help to read the manual http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop.

Comment: I read it. But couldn't understand what to do.

Comment: There are some examples there, why not try them?

Comment: `inline` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. You can try `str2func` and/or `sym`/`symfun`. Also, consider writing a [function](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html) with input arguments instead of using `input`. Finally, if you have an error, it would be helpful to provide it in full (and indicate what you're inputting that causes it so we replicate the issue). This sounds like a programming issue and thus off-topic for this site. You should probably close it and ask an improved version at [StackOverflow.com/Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).

Answer (score 1):

```
x=sym('x');
func=input('enter function as function of x');
f=inline(func);
fprime=diff(func);
```